TYPO3 get page resources first media image file url of parent page in fluid template
I try to output the first image referenced in the page properties tab "Resources" media relations of the parent page of the current page in a fluid template.
I have got the parent page's id as data.pid.
Specifically I want the image's url.
I have tried <f:image treatIdAsReference="1" src="{v:page.info(pageUid:\"{data.pid}\", field:\"media\")}" /> to no avail (got TYPO3 Exception No file reference (sys_file_reference) was found for given UID: "1"). I believe the media field is only a counter of number of relations added.
I have tried the vhs ViewHelper by {v:page.resources(uid: '{data.pid}') -> v:iterator.first() -> v:variable.set(name: 'image')} but the resulting image variable is only the char '1' and when passed to f:image an exception along the lines of "src must be string or FileObject" is thrown.
I know of the sys_file_reference table but I didn't find a predefined fluid template mean (eg. a ViewHelper) to access the uid of the file or file reference when I know the page id.

Btw.: the only way to get the current page's page properties tab "Resources" first media relation image file url I got working is {f:uri.image(src:"/fileadmin/{data_pageimage.0.originalFile.identifier}")}. All other means I tried by ViewHelper such as f:uri.image complained about the src not being a reference (treatIdAsReference true), src being data.media, or the getter of some data_pageimage.0 subobject's id was protected.
If a general way exists to get an image's url by providing a page id and a page properties "file field"'s name (so also for og_image) I'll be glad to read about it.
We are using TYPO3 12 LTS.

Have a look at the FilesProcessor. It can serve you the object you want to use in your template.
Media from current page
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
    # ... (your other stuff)

    # Before TYPO3 v12.1 you have to specify the fully-qualified class name of the processor
    # dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    # Since TYPO3 v12.1 one can also use the available alias
    dataProcessing.10 = files
    dataProcessing.10 {
        as = mediaimages
        references.fieldName = media
        references.table = pages
    }
}

Media from parent page
For selecting media of another page in your rootline, you can use levelmedia
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
    # ... (your other stuff)

    # Before TYPO3 v12.1 you have to specify the fully-qualified class name of the processor
    # dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    # Since TYPO3 v12.1 one can also use the available alias
    dataProcessing.10 = files
    dataProcessing.10 {
        as = mediaimages
        references.data = levelmedia: -1
    }
}

After this preparation, you can simply access the files via {mediaimages} and by the index:
<f:image image='{mediaimages.0}' />


That would not consider the parent page but the current page. For the parent page you might need a nested dataProcessing approach, that fetches the parent page record first and attaches the file record later.

Ooops, You're right, @jo-hasenau. I had overlooked this requirement. I have added an alternative with levelmedia, which then works for the images on the parent page.

Should be -2 though - but actually I'm not sure, if this returns the media values or just an integer showing the number of attached files.

Thank you very much for the example showing the FilesProcessor! I think that can make it work, either specifically for the parent page or even for any page/field combination using its references.... options. I now achieved my desire by using non-inline, non-self-closing version of a slightly different vhs ViewHelper than I originally used:
 <v:page.resources.fal field="media" uid="{data.pid}" as="images">
    ... <!-- images.0 (if count() > 0) is a file reference and works successfully in appropriate f:uir.image ViewHelper for example-->
</v:page.resources.fal>


@LarsHansen uid="{data.pid}" will be broken for translations of pages though.

@JoHasenau will it? we use translations in another project, I leave this as to be solved then when we cross it.
